# How do I turn the $input automatic variable into a list (in an end block)?

Tags: powershell

Apparently, `$input` is of type `System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple`, and not just `Object[]`. And `[Object[]]$input` fails. I guess I could just manually add pipeline elements to my own `$input`, but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What is the use case? What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a function that operates on the whole pipeline, not individual items

Comment: Not sure I understand the difference. If you want to accept pipeline input, `$input` is not necessarily the best thing to use

Comment: I don't want to accept pipeline input, I want to process all pipeline input at once. As a whole, such that `smthn | this-func` is equivalent to `this-func-but-different (smthn)`.

Comment: Gotcha, updated the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A function that doesn't use `begin`, `process` and `end` blocks implicitly behaves as if its body were inside an `end` block; that is, the body isn't executed until after all pipeline input has been received.
- In an (implied) `end` block, you can use `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to collect all pipeline input (`$input`) in an `[object[]]` array:

```
function foo {
  $allPipelineInputAsArray = @($input) # creates [object[]] array
  $allPipelineInputAsArray.ForEach({ "[$_]" }) # sample output
}
```

The above relies on `$input` implementing the [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerator) interface, which means that you can also use it directly in a `foreach` loop, for instance:

```
function foo {
  foreach ($obj in $input) {
    "[$obj]" # sample output.
  }
}
```

Both function definitions, when invoked as `1..3 | foo`, yield the following:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

**Caveat**: If you define your function as an [*advanced* (cmdlet-like) function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) (explicitly, via a `[CmdletBinding(...)]` attribute or implicitly, via a `[Parameter(...)]` attribute, the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input) is no longer available - you would then have to manually collect all input objects in a list data structure via the `process` block, which you can then process in the `end` block - see the second  function definition in [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61972818/45375).

Also note that by using this approach you're forgoing the core feature of the PowerShell pipeline, namely the memory-throttling, one-by-one processing of input objects (you're collecting all input objects in memory); however, this would likely only become a problem with very large input sets.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `[Object[]] $input`

Since `$input` doesn't implement [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) - only its auxiliary `IEnumerator` interface - this cast doesn't cause the enumerator `$input` to be walked; instead, the *enumerator object itself* is cast to `[object[]]`, which is not the intent.

To put it differently: **`$input` isn't the collection of input objects, it is a helper object for *enumerating* the collection of input objects**.

Answer (score 1):

Use the array subexpression operator `@()` to "extract" all items from the enumerator:

```bsh
function f
{
  end {
    # this will be of type [object[]]
    $InputItems = @($input)
  }
}
```

---

If you want to support pipeline input *and* non-pipeline input all the same, use the following pattern:

- Declare an array-type input parameter

  - Mark it `ValueFromPipeline`
- Use the `process` block to "collect" all input items that might come in via the pipeline
- Execute actual code against your collected pipeline items in the `end` block:

```bsh
function f
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [object[]]$InputObject)

  begin {
    $AllInputItems = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
  }

  process {
    $AllInputItems.AddRange($InputObject)
  }

  end {
    # Work on $AllInputItems down here
  }
}
```

Now the user can do:

```
1,2,3 |f
# or
f 1,2,3
```

Comment: Why do you omit the space after all of the `|`s?

Comment: @schuelermine Because I find it more aesthetically pleasing, a purely stylistic choice